# Add or change a related_name argument

Tags: django, django-models, django-related-manager

**Django: 3.0.6**

Below is my attempt to organize tags and tags for admin staff only (django-taggit is used).

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager # django-taggit
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase # django-taggit

class SpecialAdminTaggedPost(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey('Post',
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                       related_name="admin_tagged_post")


class Post(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager() # django-taggit
    admin_tags = TaggableManager(through=SpecialAdminTaggedPost) # django-taggit.
```

This gives the following error:

```
ERRORS:
post.Post.admin_tags: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Post.admin_tags' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Post.tags'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Post.admin_tags' or 'Post.tags'.
post.Post.tags: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Post.tags' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Post.admin_tags'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Post.tags' or 'Post.admin_tags'.
System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

Docs (not sure if it is of any help here): https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10/custom_tagging.html

How can I cope with this problem?

Comment: Did you make migration?

Comment: When makimg migrations the same error appear.

Comment: Is there any field related with Post model in your TaggedItemBase class?

Comment: It is a class from django-taggit. It is imported. I edited my question to show it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `related_name` in the model description as well. I ran into the same problem.

Your updated model like this would work:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager(related_name='tags') 
    admin_tags = TaggableManager(related_name='admin_tags',
                                 through=SpecialAdminTaggedPost)
```

I noticed that yes even if you use the `related_name` same as your model's field (i.e. `tags` and `admin_tags` in your case), it still works just fine.

Then you'd naturally go about accessing the tags for your post model:

```py
<post_object>.tags 
# or 
<post_object>.admin_tags
```

All the APIs are listed [here](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem when I mistakenly replaced models.py in one Django app by another models.py. So I had two exact copy of models.py in different apps. Pls check is everything ok with your models.py.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please check [how to write good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Suggestion can be provided in comments.